# Google Dialogflow webhook not firing due billing issues

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

I would like to fire some function when a user enters some input into my chat-bot, but for some reason billing it seems to be enabled, eventhough I am not making any external call outside Google.

I am only showing the initial function and the code looks as below:

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
      console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
      console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
      if (request.body.result) {
        processV1Request(request, response);
      } else if (request.body.queryResult) {
        processV2Request(request, response);
      } else {
        console.log('Invalid Request');
        return response.status(400).end('Invalid Webhook Request (expecting v1 or v2 webhook request)');
      }
    });
```

Just so you know I have created a separate Console Firebase project and not using Dialogflow Inline Editor, is this the reason it is complaining about the billing?

Comment: What exactly is not working the way you expect? What is happening in `processV1Request` and `processV2Request`?

Comment: well nothing is happening for some reason it seems is stopping since it is complaining about the billing in the firebase logs. but I am not using any external outbound call or smth. Do you want me to show u the processV1Request, processV1Request functions? eventhou i havent changed anything on it, its the google default functions

Comment: Please be very specific about the code that's not working the way you intend and logs that show the error.

Comment: @DougStevenson I dont know if I can be more specific than this: Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions, I am getting this from the Firebase Logs from the code being executed within the dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment function. Google says that u need to change the plan to make exertnal call, but I am not making any external call!

Comment: @DougStevenson one tip that might help, If I am using the Dialogflow Fullfillment Inline Editor the same code it works there, does not complain about billing, but when I try to swtich to webhook and enter my webhook URL and ENABLE it then it complains

Comment: Other than the warnings about billing, what is not working the way you expect? Cloud Functions work on the Firebase free tier, you just can't make outgoing requests to non-Google operated services.

Comment: Firebase logs doesnt display anything else, and I dont know why my webhook function is not responding to my chatbot dialogflow!

do u have any suggestion on how do I make sure my chatbot is calling my firebase cloud function? well I think it is calling since I get the billing complain only when I enter something on the chatbot input and submit it!

Comment: The warning is just a warning - if you're not making external calls, then it doesn't impact you. But the question remains - why do you think it isn't working? What are you expecting it to do? What is it doing instead? What are you seeing or not seeing and where? Are you seeing the headers and body?